# Embeding Youtube Video in website

Tags: html, css, youtube

I want to put a video on my website using the embed option on youtube. I have added it the code is below.

That code is working fine in Firefox browser but not working in other browser. Suggest me the solution.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;width: 100%; height: 461.25px; float: none; clear: both; margin: 2px auto;">

<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vfGRnSiRWcE?rel=0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" title="Adobe Flash Player">
```

Comment: Code : <div style="width:100%;height:100%;width: 100%; height: 461.25px; float: none; clear: both; margin: 2px auto;">
 <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vfGRnSiRWcE?rel=0&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" title="Adobe Flash Player">

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframe HTML tag, iframeworks on all browsers.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vfGRnSiRWcE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```